# Java AssertEquals in catch

Tags: java, junit

```
    @Test
  void testSomething() {
    try {
      //something that would throw an exception.
  } catch (Exception e) {
    assertEquals(true, false);
  }
```

If I have something like this in my j unit test, would the test still fail?

EDIT: Sorry should've stated earlier, I'm not trying to achieve anything here this is part of my midterm and someone told me any assertEquals in catch will always pass and I was confused about that.

Comment: why don't you try it and see?

Comment: Why not let the exception propagate? Or at least `assertFalse()`?

Answer (score 2):

It would still fail, because you're trying to assert a condition that will never be true:

```
assertEquals(true, false);
```

That will, by itself, throw an `AssertionError`, which is not being caught, so the overall unit test will fail.

Answer (score 1):

The preferred way of asserting exception is by using expected like this:
for example, you expect the test should throw ArithmeticException

```
@Test(expected = ArithmeticException.class)
public void div_shouldThrowArithmeticExceptionWhenDivisorIsZero() {
    int a = 10, b = 0;
    div(a,b);
}
```

if you specify `@Test(expected = SomeExpectedException.class)`, then the test will pass when the test code block generate the expected Exception.

Answer (score -1):

Whenever exception throws from try block your assertequals in catch block will execute but I'm not sure about your intention of doing that. If you want to assert about your exception you can do that by assert Throws.

I hope this answer helps